Unable to build starknet contracts (probably macros or version issue)
I’m trying to learn StarkNet by following the counter workshop from the StarkNet Edu GitHub repository, but I am stuck with an error when trying to compile my Cairo contract.
#[starknet::contract]
 pub mod counter_contract {
#[storage]
struct Storage {}
}

(venv) admin@admins-MacBook-Air counter-workshop % scarb build
Compiling counter v0.1.0 
(/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/Starknet/counter- 
workshop/Scarb.toml)
error: Plugin diagnostic: Unsupported attribute.
--> /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/Starknet/counter- 
workshop/src/counter.cairo:1:1
#[starknet::contract]
^*******************^

error: Plugin diagnostic: Unsupported attribute.
--> /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/Starknet/counter- 
workshop/src/counter.cairo:3:5
#[storage]
^********^

error: could not compile `counter` due to previous error

I have tried installing different versions of dependencies but am still encountering the same issue.


Following steps from the second step of the lesson did the trick for me.

Add starknet = ">=2.8.0" under [dependencies] to Scarb.toml
Build using scarb build
Now set the target as [[target.starknet-contract]]


I fixed mine by installing rust and cargo on my machine first, using this command
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh

for more info on how to install it, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html
After that,

Add starknet = ">=2.8.0" under [dependencies] to Scarb.toml
set the target as [[target.starknet-contract]]
run the command scarb build

...this should probably work.
